# Missing - Click To Edit links in SharePoint List/Library settings

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, edit-form, newform, display-form

We have two SharePoint Web Application (IIS sites) one running on http port 80 and other on port 1234.

Web app on port 1234 has one site collection and few sub sites, document libraries, lists etc.

On this site collection, a weird issue is coming. If library/list settings page is opened, any links to open/edit Column names, view names or content name are not visible.

This effectively means user can create additional columns, but cannot edit them later because there are no visible links.

Even if a new list is created anywhere on this site collection, these links to listedit.aspx, ViewEdit.aspx, ManageContentType.aspx do not seem to appear as seen in screen shot.

So far I've checked that: listedit.aspx, ViewEdit.aspx, ManageContentType.aspx are not modified by comparing them from layouts folder of clean build SP2010 standalone installation

Any clues are appreciated.

Comment: I couldn't post screenshot because SO wants 15 rep for that..

Comment: Thanks Ondrej, will post there as well. Presumably, this is not permission issue; behaviour is consistent even for system account, and site admins or site collection admins.

Comment: do both web applications have a root site collection? do you see the views and column names (without hyperlink) or do you see nothing? any chance in a screenshot somehow (link to it or perhaps SE is more flexible than SO) ?